# Kernel PCA on each data set, not the whole matrix - Possible?

Tags: pca, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I have a matrix $X$ that has $M * n$ in size. I'm going to apply that with PCA. The problem is that $X$ contains nonlinear structures. So one good thing is to use The Kernel Trick.

My data is orginized as

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
\vdots\\ 
x_N
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where each $x_i$ has the size $m * n$. The matrix $X$, as you understand, has the same column width as each $x_i$. $M = m*N$

**Question:**

Normally, people do kernel directly on $X$. That will result a matrix with size $M * M$. Very large. What if I did kernel on each $x_i$ instead and get a $X$ matrix that has the size $M * m$ instead.

Will this work for projection, or will this fail?

Consider that every $x_i$ is an image matrix.